# Error:Android Studio Gradle project sync failed

Tags: android-studio

**JDK is the latest version**

```
    Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
    This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
    For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
    Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should review your local.properties file and check your sdk.dir.
More information about daemon configuration is available on http://gradle.org/docs/2.2.1/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties